# Xamarin Line Break in label for long words in german

Tags: xaml, xamarin, label, line-breaks

I´m developing an app in xamarin and I have the next scenario.

I have a label with maxLines = 3, for some long words in german or french the line break doesn't separate the words syllabels correctly, for example the correct separation of the word "Bezirksschornsteinfegermeister" is "Bezirkss–chorn–ste–in–fegermeis–ter" but in the app is showing like this

[image]

It should be Bezirksschorn(First Line) steinfegermeister(Second Line)

This is my code

```
<Label
Margin="24,0,24,14"
FontSize="18"
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
MaxLines="3"
Text="Bezirksschornsteinfegermeister"
VerticalTextAlignment="End" />
```

The line break for long words works fine for english words but not for german or french words. There is any library that make a correct line break separation for german and french?

Comment: is your device locale set to German?  My guess is that the underlying behavior is driven by the OS, not something internally in XF

Comment: Yes, my device locale is set to german

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the options for `LineBreakMode` in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#truncation-and-wrapping) as below:

- **HeadTruncation** – truncates the head of the text, showing the end.
- **CharacterWrap** – wraps text onto a new line at a character boundary.
- **MiddleTruncation** – displays the beginning and end of the text, with the middle replace by an ellipsis.
- **NoWrap** – does not wrap text, displaying only as much text as can fit
  on one line.
- **TailTruncation** – shows the beginning of the text, truncating the end.
  WordWrap – wraps text at the word boundary.

Obviously,we can't divide a long string into separate words.You may need add spacing or other characters to separate words.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Xamarin issue, if you are testing on Android then German language is not supported, only English, check [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37087785). Not sure about the iOS.